# RibbonUI Documentation - Controls and Attributes

Tags: vba, excel, ribbon

I'm aware that questions asking for "favorite off-site resources" are generally off-topic here, but I am having a great deal of difficulty locating the VBA documentation for Microsoft's RibbonUI/XML attributes.

I'm hoping that someone else who does RibbonUI development might have that link handy.

I think it was on MSDN, and contained a list of the control types *and* the allowable attributes. I can't find *anything* like that the past few days.

About a week or two ago, I did have the link and I thought I had bookmarked it. I am pretty sure it was on MSDN.

This is *close* to what I had been using:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608623.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.aspx

But the list I had included controls, their respectively allowed attributes and callback procedures (e.g., it would indicate which controls could use `getVisible`, etc. and which control types *shared* common attributes with other control types.)

It was particularly useful for someone who is developing without VSTO or other GUI Ribbon Editor.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "favorite" off-site resource, since you are just asking for the documentation link. Seems fine to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was what I was looking for:

[Descriptions, Attributes, and Child Information for the Ribbon Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199.aspx#OfficeCustomizingRibbonUIforDevelopers2_Detailed)

Far too much to reproduce in full here, but as an example, this is the sort of information contained about the various UI controls: which attributes/callbacks are available, some basic documentation about what each does, which are shared with other controls, etc.

[image]